# Using Joomla 2.5, is there a way to link from the frontend to a backend component without login?

Tags: php, html, joomla, content-management-system

The title says most of it, but is there a way to link from a page in the front end to a component in the backend WITHOUT asking the user to login again. Some thoughts come to mind, Sessions tables, and cookies, but I'm just not sure how to go about doing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla! runs as two separate applications, one for the front-end and one for the back-end.

To do what you're suggesting is problematic:

1. Any system you implement to get this working could compromise site security.
2. You would have to find/build a mechanism that logs the user into both the front-end and back at the same time.
3. As both back-end & front-end use different tokens and sessions you would also have to keep both of those alive as well.
4. As part of this process your software should probably limit back-end auto logins to those with the right permissions as well.

I'm not aware of any extensions that do what you want but there are some that allow some backend functionality in the front-end - you can look in [the "Site Access" section of the JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a frontend view for the component you want to display? For example **[like this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=471&t=226476)**.